# Using flood fill algorithm to erase specific elements of a textfile

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

For one of my classes I have a problem where I have to take all of the "cancer" cells of a text file and get rid of them using the flood fill algorithm.

This is the exact question:

> Create a program that reads a text file containing a 15 x 15 grid, which represents human cells. The cells are depicted with a plus sign “+” if they are healthy cells, and a minus sign “-” if they are cancerous. The outside rows and columns of the grid will contain only plus signs “+”. Note: Use the Flood Fill algorithm to determine this information.

So far I can get at least one of the cancer cell areas to change to `" "`, but I can't get the other. This is what I have so far. This is an example of what it should look like:

[image]

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class floodIntro {
// Make global variables (grid&blobSize) which are accessible
// from anywhere inside the class FloodIntro
public static Character newGrid[][];
public static int blobSize;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    String[] grid = new String[15];
    newGrid = new Character[15][15];

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("location.txt"));
    String str = null;
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i = 0;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        grid[i] = str;
    //  System.out.println(str);
        i++;
    }

    // so far can print out every line listed above
    for (int x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
        // for every line in the grid
        for (int y = 0; y < grid[x].length(); y++) {
            newGrid[x][y] = grid[x].charAt(y);
            }       
    }


    // Print out the current grid
    displayGrid();

    // variable to determine the size of the blob
    blobSize = 0;

    // Pick one random element in the array that is not along the
    // border and remove the blob at that location
    // NOTE: if a blank is chosen, the blob size is 0
    // and nothing is removed
    int blobRow = (int) (Math.random() * 13 + 1);
    int blobCol = (int) (Math.random() * 13 + 1);

    System.out.println("The blob at " + blobRow + "," + blobCol + " will be removed.");
    floodFill(blobRow, blobCol);
    System.out.println("The blob had " + blobSize + " items in it");
    System.out.println("The new grid is:");
    // Print out the new grid
    displayGrid();
}

public static void floodFill(int row, int col) {
    if (newGrid[row][col].equals('-')) {
        newGrid[row][col] = ' ';
        blobSize++;
        floodFill(row - 1, col - 1);
        floodFill(row - 1, col);
        floodFill(row - 1, col + 1);
        floodFill(row, col - 1);
        floodFill(row, col + 1);
        floodFill(row + 1, col - 1);
        floodFill(row + 1, col);
        floodFill(row + 1, col + 1);
    }
}

  public static void displayGrid() {
      String output="";
        for (int row = 0; row <= 14; row++) {
          for (int col = 0; col <= 14; col++) {
            output += newGrid[row][col];
          }
          output += "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(output);
      }
}
```

Here is the txt file being used:

```
+++++++++++++++
++--+++++++++++
++---++++++++++
+----++++++++++
++++-++++++++++
+++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++
+++++++++-----+
+++++++-----+++
+++++-----+++++
++++++------+++
+++++++-----+++
+++++++++--++++
++++++++++-++++
+++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that the random generation of locations:

```
int blobRow = (int) (Math.random() * 13 + 1);
int blobCol = (int) (Math.random() * 13 + 1);
```

Might not end up at a `-`, thus doesn't do anything (it doesn't go into the if-statement if you get a `+`).

You can see in [this demo](http://ideone.com/fRjCt3) that it does fill a cancer spot correctly if you pass it valid coordinates.

Beyond this, you should actually run flood-fill a few times (once for each cancer spot). Something like:

1. Look for a `-` (by looping through the entire grid)
2. If found:

   - Increment a counter (since you need to output the number of cancer spots)
   - Proceed with flood-fill from there
   - And repeat from #1

Comment: Thank you so much! I just needed the generally idea to loop back through. It took me literally 2 seconds to apply a quick fix. There is just one thing to fix and that is print out that there is only 2 full cancer cells.